# C# force X Axis to stay between 60 and -60/simple flying script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I short: I want to make a simple flying script.

The Object stops at 60, but if it tries to go below 0, it will jump to 60. If I'm forcing the object in the editor to -40 and press W to lower it, it will jump to 60 too.

Rotating only works properly between 0 and 60.

And no, setting the default rotation to 180,0,180 and trying to use `maxRotation = 260` and `minRotation = 60` don't make any difference.

```
    float minRotation = -60;
    float maxRotation = 60;

    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("W");

        Vector3 currentRotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x-1f, minRotation, maxRotation);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(currentRotation.x, 0f, 0f);

    }
    if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("S");
        Vector3 currentRotation = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
        currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x+1f, minRotation, maxRotation);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not super familiar with unity, but it seems weird to me that you are setting the rotation in two different ways. `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(currentRotation.x, 0f, 0f);` vs `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);`.

Comment: The outcome stays the same. with both lines, i doesn't do what i should.

Comment: If i try somethin like this:

//Not working
  if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
        {
            if (transform.eulerAngles.x > 260f)
            {
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
 
            }
        }
 
//Working
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") < 0)
        {
            if (transform.eulerAngles.x < 60f)
            {
                transform.Rotate(new Vector3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
 
            }
        }

The Object goes in evry cas to 90 an is jittering like a maniac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Rotator : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float minRotation = -60f;
    private float maxRotation = 60f;
    private float currentAngle;
    private float rotationSpeed = 20f;
    private Quaternion baseRotation;
    private Vector3 rotationDirection = Vector3.right;

    private void Start()
    {
        baseRotation = transform.rotation;
    }   

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0)
        {
            currentAngle += Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            currentAngle = Mathf.Clamp(currentAngle, minRotation, maxRotation);

            var rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(currentAngle, rotationDirection);
            transform.rotation = rotation * baseRotation;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Using AngleAxis and this: currentAngle += Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxis("Vertical")) * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime; are great solutions, i didn't thought about something like that. Thank you very much, i've learned something. :-)

Comment: Last question. Ho can i restirct this to x? beacause i'm rotating the y axis too. My big problem is, that i've never needet to use such stuff.